extrafonts does not recognise National 2 font family
I recently installed National 2 font on Windows. Using font_import() from extrafonts, National 2 is skipped over. Calling fonts() shows that National 2 has not been installed.
Opening Power Point I can see the font has been recognised by Office products. Specifying a pattern (ie 'National') in the call to font_import() throws the following error;
Error in data.frame(fontfile = ttfiles, FontName = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) :
   arguments imply differenting number of rows: 0, 1   

Inspecting C:/Windows/fonts, I can see that National 2 is present, but it is a font family package. Selecting the font family I can see there are 16 variants inside. These cannot be moved up a level into the general fonts folder.
One observation is that other font family packages (ie Lucida Fax) seem to be imported, however, when they do get imported only a single font is imported (none of the variants are included).
My workplace does use application control, however ttf2pt1.exe has been approved (as I am able to import existing font files).
Has anyone encountered this issue with importing installed font families with extrafont?

Guessing from the error message (..., FontName = "", ...): does specifying the FontName, which might vary with font family, e.g.: FancyFontBold, FancyFontItalic, help?
